# How to format citation and references according to Artificial Intelligence Review journal?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I am absolutely new to Latex and have learnt some of it's features by searching over the Internet. I managed to get the body of my paper formatted according to the AI Review journal but got stuck during citation and referencing. According to the template they provided on their website, I wrote like this:

```
...the real production process \cite{ref1}(Henry, Cao (2016) describes the impact on...

% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\bibliography{}   % name your BibTeX data base

% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{spbasic}
    \bibitem{ref1}
    Henry SM, Cao Y (2016) Paper Title. Journal:pages. https://doi.org/10.1/xxxx
\end{thebibliography}
```

The output is like this:
[image]

But according to the journal's requirements, there should be **no numbering** in the citation as well as the reference list. I tried several methods suggested by overleaf.com and other websites but none of those conform to the journal's format. Moreover, a **hyperlink** should work between the citation and the relevant reference. I would like to appreciate anybody there to suggest me any good solution to this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more what exactly you're doing. In particular, do please tell us if you use BibTeX (along with which bibliography style) to create the formatted bibliography or if you build the contents of the `thebibliography` environment by hand.

Comment: I don't have better idea. I tried both way without proper result. In the above demo, I tried manually as you can see, but I am flexible to go with BibTeX too.

Comment: For sure, if you used BibTeX along with the `spbasic` bib style, you should have been getting authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Using "spbasic", I got like this as citation "[Hadui and Chinar(1905)]". Also in reference list, I got "[Hadui and Chinar(1905)] Hadui SM, Chinar Y (1905) ...". How should I get rid of those square brackets at citation and the whole index at reference list?

Comment: The instructions given in your template file are woefully incomplete and inadequate. When using the `spbasic` bib style, one should also load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `authoryear`, i.e., `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`. To play it safe, you should also run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: @Mico I tried a lot with natbib and several other packages but no result. Would you please have a look at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10462-021-10008-0 for the Bibliography style? Any way, thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124842/discussion-between-ps-nayak-and-mico).